# Windows file share: why sometimes newly created files aren't visible for some period of time?

Tags: windows, server-message-block

***Please note, I copied this question from SO, because understood that ServerFault is better place for such kind of questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159220)***

Hello

We were faced with very strange issue that made us crazy. Sometimes newly created files on our File Share PC were "absent" for some period of time. To reproduce a problem you should have at least two computers, call them `alpha` and `beta`. Create file share on `beta` PC (`\\beta\share\bug`) and run this PowerShell script from `alpha` PC:

```
param(
  $sharePath="\\beta\share\bug"
)
$sharePC = ($sharePath -split '\\')[2]
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $sharePC
$counter = 0
while ($true) {
  $fileName = $sharePath + "\$counter.txt"
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    param(
      $fileName
    )
    "" > $fileName
  } -ArgumentList $fileName
  if (Test-Path $fileName) {
    Write-Host "File $fileName exists" -fore Green
  } else {
    Write-Host "!!! File $fileName does NOT exist!" -fore Red
  }

  $counter = $counter + 1
  Start-Sleep 2
}
```

After starting this script you should be able to see these messages:

```
File \\beta\share\bug\1.txt exists
File \\beta\share\bug\2.txt exists
...
```

**And now**:
Open `cmd.exe` and run this command:

`if exist \\beta\share\bug\foo.txt echo 1`

After this you'll during approx 10 seconds you'll see following messages:

```
!!! File \\beta\share\bug\3.txt does NOT exist!
!!! File \\beta\share\bug\4.txt does NOT exist!
```

We've discovered that bug is caused by enumerating shared directory where new files are being created. In `Python` call `os.listdir('//beta/share/bug')` to reproduce a bug. In `C#`: `Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\beta\share\bug")`. You can even simply navigate to share directory by shell and call `ls` or `dir`.

Bug were found on `Windows Server 2008 R2`. Bug also can be reproduced on `Windows 7` (on both OSs `SMB 2.0` is installed)

Note, that you cannot watch directory content on `alpha` PC in Windows Explorer in real time, because if you open this directory in Explorer bug would not occur! So ensure to close all such windows before attempts to reproduce a bug. After each script restart you should manually remove all already created files from share (because script is rather stupid and always starts from 0.txt).

We currently have 2 workarounds for this issue:

1. If client sees this situation, it creates some temporary file in problematic directory - after this files magically appear.
2. Disable SMB 2.0: http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-disable-smb-2-on-windows-vista-or-server-2008.htm

Does anybody have ever discovered similar problem and can explain why it occurs and how "correctly fix" it?

Thanks

Comment: One point to clarify...you said that one workaround is to create a temp file then everything appears. Does that mean that in your counting-up script, each file you create means all the previous files appear, since each created file would be like creating a temp file?

Comment: Is there something related to the process not releasing a file handle before the files appear in directory listings?

Comment: If you have a person on computer B creating files on a share on computer A, you're saying that someone on computer C can't browse to \\a\share and hit refresh to have the files made by B show up? For how long? Any indication how long that takes for them to be listed?

Comment: Bart, counting loop creates files in remote session on behalf on beta computer, workaround requires alpha's user to create temp file, because beta can always see files it has created.

I don't think it is problem with not releasing file handle.

About time to wait to files: as I mentioned in post it is approx 10 seconds. And yes, that someone wouldn't see new files in case of described issue.

Comment: I am having problems here. Does anyone have any idea what is causing it. I would prefer not to change the smb version as 2.x offers significant speed improvements over 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our current solution that just works: Disable SMB 2.0 (http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-disable-smb-2-on-windows-vista-or-server-2008.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not wanting to downgrade the performance of your smb services modify the following registry settings on your smb client.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Lanmanworkstation\Parameters
```

set `DirectoryCacheLifetime`, `FileNotFoundCacheLifetime` and `FileInfoCacheLifetime` to 0.

Fix is outlined [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winserverfiles/thread/b50d1400-252e-4a6e-b3a9-5276cf9093c7) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/28ae628b-bf2e-4aae-882c-816d75e1110b).

Comment: I would say this is the way to go.  SMB2 has some performance improvements, so disabling SMB2 should only be temporary.